# What, if any, are the differences between the UK and North American versions of Kingdom Hearts Birth by Sleep Final Mix in the 2.5 HD Remix?

Tags: version-differences, kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep, kingdom-hearts-2.5-remix

What, if any, are the differences between the UK and North American versions of Kingdom Hearts Birth by Sleep Final Mix in the Kingdom Hearts 2.5 HD Remix?

I'm not asking about like packaging or different cover art or anything like that—are there any actual differences within the game itself, (gameplay, cutscenes, items, Unversed, colour schemes, just anything at all within the actual game) or are they exactly the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I live in the US and have to North American version. In mine auto-starts on English but I do have the option to change it to German, French, Spanish or Italian voice over or subs. So I don't believe there is any differences.

Comment: Hmm, so according to this answer, there are **no** differences at all. But has anyone had access to both NA and PAL versions to be able to verify for sure?

Comment: Okay well, I guess this is the closest thing I'm ever going to get to an “authoritative” answer, so… best answer? I guess?

Answer (score 0):

**The only differences would be the language selection.** The PAL version of the game allows choices between English, German, French, Spanish, and Italian voiceovers/subtitles.

There are no other differences between either version of the games.

Comment: Whereas in the North American version, it just automatically selects English? But everything else is the same, if I'm understanding you correctly?

Comment: The NA version is only in (US) English, with no language selection option.